# Referencing a children from a custom control

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, custom-controls, setcontentview

I'm creating a custom control by composing some elements in a `ContentView`. The `ContentView` has another nested `ContentView` called `MainBody`. 
How would i access and set `MainBody` when i'm using the control. This is what i want to achieve:

```
...
<controls.ControlName>
    <controls.ControlName.MainBody>
        <ContentView>
            ...
        </ContentView>
    </controls.ControlName.MainBody>
</controls.ControlName>
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is what i came up with:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty MainContentProperty = BindableProperty.Create("MainContent", typeof(View), typeof(DropShadowPanel), default(View));

        public View MainContent
        {
            get { return (View)GetValue(MainContentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MainContentProperty, value); OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public DropShadowPanel ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            PropertyChanged += DropShadowPanel_PropertyChanged;
        }

        private void DropShadowPanel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.PropertyName == MainContentProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                mainContent.Content = MainContent;
            }
        }
```

And it works.